# Python: Why does this work?

Tags: python

I'd like some help clarifying the logic behind this.

```
from operator import add, sub

def a_plus_abs_b(a, b):
    if b < 0:
        f = sub # subtract a negative value
    else:
        f = add # add a positive one
    return f(a, b)
```

I originally thought that I would have to think of some complex mathematical expression to allow this function to work, but someone showed me that just adding sub and add to f allows it to work properly. I'm having difficulty trying seeing how this works, so any clarifying remarks would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is actually one of the cool and powerful features of python!

Comment: What do you mean why it works? This is how the language is. You assign a function to `f` but haven't executed it until the end. I'm not sure what you're asking for?

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work. This will throw an indentation error.

Comment: I think we all understands what he means though (and the post seems to have a pending edit).

Answer (score 2):

Well, the logic itself works because `a + abs(b) == a + b` when `b >= 0` and `a + abs(b) == a - b` when `b < 0`. I have commented out your code below.

```
from operator import add, sub
# two functions are imported:
#   add(x,y) -> (x + y)
#   sub(x,y) -> (x - y)

def a_plus_abs_b(a, b):

    # when b < 0, (a + abs(b)) == (a - b)
    if b < 0:
        # f is a temporary variable holding the function sub
        f = sub

    # when b >= 0, (a + abs(b)) == (a + b)
    else:
        # f is a temporary variable holding the function add
        f = add

    # apply the arguments to the function determined above
    return f(a, b)
```

However, this function could be written in a single line.

```
def a_plus_abs_b(a, b):
    return a + abs(b)
```

The interesting thing about your function is that it highlights that functions are first-order objects in Python. This means that they can be passed around and assigned to variables and many other things.

Answer (score 1):

`sub` is just the name of a reference to a function object that implements subtraction. Like any other reference, you can assign its value to another name, so `f = sub` simply makes `f` another name for reference stored in `sub`. As such, `f(a, b)` and `sub(a, b)` both call the same underlying function.